Why are additional elements added when calling XmlWriter.WriteCData(String) method?
I need to write the value of other xml nodes containing CDATA sections  into the CDATA section of an XML node (I use .NET 6)
For example, I need to generate and write the following XML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<items>
      <item><![CDATA[<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]></some_node>]]</item>
</items>

To generate the XML, I use the following code:
string str_xml = String.Empty;
    
using (MemoryStream m_stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter xml_writer = XmlWriter.Create(m_stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Encoding = Encoding.UTF8, Indent = true, OmitXmlDeclaration = false }))
    {
        xml_writer.WriteStartElement("items");
        xml_writer.WriteStartElement("item");
        xml_writer.WriteCData("<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]></some_node>");
        xml_writer.WriteFullEndElement();
    
        xml_writer.WriteEndElement();
        xml_writer.Flush();
    }
    
    m_stream.Position = 0;
    using (StreamReader stream_reader = new StreamReader(m_stream))
    {
        str_xml = stream_reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}

The value of the str_xml variable in the debugger:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <items>
       <item>
          <![CDATA[<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]]]><![CDATA[></some_node>]]>
       </item>
    </items>

Why is the value in the CDATA section of the item node incorrectly formed?

I doubt you need to add the [CDATA] tags inside the writeCData. You should only use the actual CDATA there.

It seems to me that your aim is invalid to start with, or at least isn't what you really expect it to be. Your "expected" value contains a CDATA node with text <some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value, and then just plain text of ></some_node>]], because the first ]] terminates the CDATA.

Can't <some_node> just be a regular child node of <item>? If you really need to nest CDATA sections, then you could encrypt the inner one a base64.

Your data is already CData so just write using Raw data instead of CData.

The expected <item><![CDATA[<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]></some_node>]]</item> is not well-formed XML (for I what I assume is your intention). CDATA blocks cannot be nested. You need to use a sequence of CDATA blocks. The value in the debugger is well-formed XML. <![CDATA[<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]]]><![CDATA[></some_node>]]> is two CDATA blocks. The first block contains <some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]] and the second block contains ></some_node>.

@jdweng it seems that the string "<some_node><![CDATA[cdata_value]]></some_node>" is intended to be wrapped by a CDATA block. It is not raw data. WriteCData is seeing the CDATA within the string and is, correctly, producing a sequence of CDATA blocks.

@JonathanDodds : I'm answering the OP question "Why is item node incorrectly formed"

@JonathanDodds: you are right, CDATA sections cannot contain nested CDATA sections
https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-CDEnd
This is my mistake, I didn't know about it.
The wikipedia section (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#Nesting) says:
This means that to encode "]]>" in the middle of a CDATA section, replace all occurrences of "]]>" with the following:
]]]]><![CDATA[>
It looks like XmlWriter does the same thing.
But with this approach, is another CDATA section nested in the first CDATA section anyway?

@Olivier Jacot-Descombes Good idea, I'll use this approach, thank you. I need to write a log with parameters (the value of each parameter is XML where CDATA sections are possible) and the log itself must be in the XML format

You're trying to produce something that isn't XML, so it's not surprising that it doesn't work. CDATA sections in XML can't be nested.
What's happening is that when you try to write CDATA containing ]]>, the XMLWriter knows that that wouldn't be well-formed because it would end the CDATA section, so it closes the first CDATA section and starts a new one. There are various ways of handling this and different libraries will do it differently, but they will all end up with something along these lines.
The inner CDATA content, cdata_value doesn't need to be in CDATA at all because it doesn't contain any special characters like < or &.

It is better to use LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.
There is no need to mushroom CData sections. Just one will do the job.
c#
void Main()
{
    string cdata_content = @"<root>My inner XML</root>";

    XElement xelem = new XElement("items",
          new XElement("item",
          new XCData(cdata_content)));
    
    Console.WriteLine(xelem);

    //xelem.Save(<FileName>);
}

Output
<items>
  <item><![CDATA[<root>My inner XML</root>]]></item>
</items>


I'm wary of suggesting that people switch to a different technology without knowing anything about their project constraints. For example, building a LINQ tree in memory and then serializing it makes for easier coding with less potential for bugs, but it could use a lot more memory.
